# Date convert in Java

Tags: java

I want to compare two dates, for that i convert the string to date format.But during the conversion the date format changed to "02/01/2013" and "03/01/2014".It makes error in my logic.any one please tell me to how to compare two days in my date format.

```
      String fdate="01/02/2012";
      String tdate="01/03/2013";
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      Date frmdt=new Date(fdate);
      String s1 = sdf.format(frmdt);
      Date todt=new Date(tdate);
      String s2 = sdf.format(todt);
      Date frmdate = sdf.parse(s1);
      Date todate = sdf.parse(s2);
        if(frmdate.compareTo(todate)<=0){
             //process;      
         }
```

Comment: "It makes error in my logic" doesn't explain what's going on at all. Why are you using the `Date(String)` constructor rather than calling `SimpleDateFormat.parse`?

Comment: As a side note :Date(String) constructor is deprecated

Comment: use `sdf.parse()` to get dates out of your Strings and when you compare them replace `frmdate.compareTo(todate)<=0` with `frmdate.before(todate)`. This is easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  String fs = "01/02/2012";
  String ts = "01/03/2013";
  DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
  sdf.setLenient(false);
  Date fdate = sdf.parse(fs);
  Date tdate = sdf.parse(ts);
  if (fdate.before(tdate) || f.date.equals(tdate)) {
         //process;      
  }
```

You've got too much going on.  It's much simpler.

Comment: I'd suggest explicitly setting a locale and time zone, and also your comparison acts differently to the OP's if the two values are the same.

Comment: @user2508515: It will work in some locales but not others, and it won't do what it *looks* like you want if the two values are equal. (It won't execute the body of the `if` statement, whereas your original code looks like you wanted it to.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you should be calling `SimpleDateFormat.parse` instead:

```
// Using the US locale will force the use of the Gregorian calendar, and
// avoid any difficulties with different date separator symbols etc.
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // Avoid DST complications
sdf.setLenient(false);

Date fromDate = sdf.parse(fromDateText);
Date toDate = sdf.parse(toDateText);

// Alternatively: if (!fromDate.after(toDate))
if (fromDate.compareTo(toDate) <= 0) {
    ...
}
```

I'd actually suggest that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) if at all possible, where you could use a `LocalDate` type to more accurately represent your data.

Comment: Really, it's a good practice add Locale to the date format. It solves a lot of troubles in the future ;)

Comment: @TheCharliemops: I'm not sure why you've added the comment - I already do that, and say why in the answer... were you just agreeing with why I've done so?

Comment: I've seen your answer with it, but I've commented to highlight that point because it's a very good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong :)

```
String fdate="01/02/2012";
String tdate="01/03/2013";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date frmdate = sdf.parse(fdate);
Date todate = sdf.parse(tdate);
  if(frmdate.compareTo(todate)<=0){
       //process;      
   }
```

You were passing to `Date` a not parsed date with your format. Also `Date(String)` is deprecated. `DateFormat.parse(String)` is the correct one.